# COUNT the number of rows from an Except subquery

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Doing a simple `except` query works and returns my single column as I want it. My Client even gives me the count, which is what I ultimately require.

However using COUNT while using previous result as the target table returns an error.

this works:

```
(SELECT id
FROM product_to_machine
WHERE created_timestamp > "2020-12-01" AND shortcut = 0)
EXCEPT
(SELECT id
FROM product_out_of_machine)
```

it returns a single column with many values and the client prompts its size 1865r*1c.

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM(
(SELECT id
FROM product_to_machine
WHERE created_timestamp > "2020-12-01" AND shortcut = 0)
EXCEPT
(SELECT id
FROM product_out_of_machine)
)
```

This returns an error:

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9 */
```

Line 9 corresponds to the closing parenthesis.
What did I do wrong or misunderstood?

Version: MariaDB 10.4.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are too heavy with the brackets try

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT id
FROM product_to_machine
WHERE created_timestamp > "2020-12-01" AND shortcut = 0
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM product_out_of_machine
) a;
```

Also note the alias a..

Comment: Alright, so the alias is mandatory? Thanks!